# Visual Studio compiles assemblies I want to be content

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction

I have duplicate assemblies with different versions. I cannot recompile projects that use old versions of the assembly, so I manually copy the assemblies into a sub directory of my bin folder, then update the web.config with assemblybinding's.

This works fine, but now I am trying to add the old assemblies to the visual studio project so that they will be deployed to the build directory. But, visual studio keeps looking at these assemblies and telling me I have a version conflict! Therefore, I cant compile the project...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cant have the same assembly referenced twice in one program, even if they are different version, it's just the way visual studio works. You need to reconstruct and recompile the code that references the older assemblies using the new versions of the assembly. This can be done via a reflector, and is relatively easy if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm not trying to refer to the old assemblies, and I dont want visual studio to add a reference to it. I want it to blindly add it as content that will be deployed to the build directory.

Comment: sorry, I noticed someone changed my url to an embedded image. It was probably hard to tell what I was trying to do in my project. I made the image a hyperlink so ppl can view it in a larger size.